# Rendering layouts/partials includes HTML tags in text after transitioning from Rails 3.0.x to 3.1

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1

I'm trying to transition an application from 3.0.7 to 3.1.  I've moved around the assets to the app/assets directory and I thought that I have everything configured correctly.

My problem is that the layout file won't correctly render partials and other layout files.  If all I have inside my layout is `<%= yield %>` then it correctly renders the view files.

But if I try to render another layout file inside layouts/omega/application.html.erb like:

```
<%= render "layouts/omega/head" %>
<%= yield %>
```

Then it dumps the html onto the page with all of the elements and html tags included in the text:

```
<div id="top-pane"> <div class="center-content">.....
"Some text that was correctly displayed from the view file that was called through yield"
```

If I try to render another file, say in home/index.html.erb:
    `<p> this is home/index </p>
    <%= render 'omega/test' %>`

Then the output will be:
    "this is home/index
    `<p> this is a test layout </p>` "
Where again, the text from home/index is outputted correctly, but the rendered partial still includes the html elements.  What's changed in 3.1 that's making this happen?

(By the way, I'm working inside a Rails Engine, which is why I have everything namespaced with omega)